# how to merge cci on 1 day time frame with technical rating on 1 hr timeframe

Tags: pine-script

basically I want to shoot an alert when CCI on 1 day time frame is above -70 and technical rating is buy or strong buy on 1 hr timeframe

I'm new to pinescript and generally a beginner in coding, I understand how indicators and alerts work but merging these two and that too on different timeframes is bit above my expertise, I would appreciate any help

I've tried something but it didn't work so I'm just putting both the indicators here for the convenience of good people of stack

Technical Ratings

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Technical Ratings", shorttitle="Technicals", precision=2)
res = input.timeframe("", title="Indicator Timeframe")
ratingSignal = input.string(defval = "All", title = "Rating is based on", options = ["MAs", "Oscillators", "All"])

useMtf1 = input(false, "", inline="mtf1", group="Show MTF")
mtf1 = input.timeframe("60", "", inline="mtf1", group="Show MTF")
useMtf2 = input(false, "", inline="mtf2", group="Show MTF")
mtf2 = input.timeframe("240", "", inline="mtf2", group="Show MTF")
useMtf3 = input(true, "", inline="mtf3", group="Show MTF")
mtf3 = input.timeframe("1D", "", inline="mtf3", group="Show MTF")
useMtf4 = input(true, "", inline="mtf4", group="Show MTF")
mtf4 = input.timeframe("1W", "", inline="mtf4", group="Show MTF")
useMtf5 = input(true, "", inline="mtf5", group="Show MTF")
mtf5 = input.timeframe("1M", "", inline="mtf5", group="Show MTF")

colBuy = input(#5b9cf6, "Buy       ", group="Color Settings", inline="Buy Colors")
colStrongBuy = input(#2962ff, "", group="Color Settings", inline="Buy Colors")
colNeutral = input(#a8adbc, "Neutral ", group="Color Settings", inline="Neutral")
colSell = input(#ef9a9a, "Sell     ", group="Color Settings", inline="Sell Colors")
colStrongSell = input(#f44336, "",  group="Color Settings", inline="Sell Colors")
tableTitleColor = input(#295b79, "Headers", group="Color Settings", inline="Headers")
// Awesome Oscillator
AO() =>
    ta.sma(hl2, 5) - ta.sma(hl2, 34)
// Stochastic RSI
StochRSI() =>
    rsi1 = ta.rsi(close, 14)
    K = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, 14), 3)
    D = ta.sma(K, 3)
    [K, D]
// Ultimate Oscillator
tl() => close[1] < low ? close[1]: low
uo(ShortLen, MiddlLen, LongLen) =>
    Value1 = math.sum(ta.tr, ShortLen)
    Value2 = math.sum(ta.tr, MiddlLen)
    Value3 = math.sum(ta.tr, LongLen)
    Value4 = math.sum(close - tl(), ShortLen)
    Value5 = math.sum(close - tl(), MiddlLen)
    Value6 = math.sum(close - tl(), LongLen)
    float UO = na
    if Value1 != 0 and Value2 != 0 and Value3 != 0
        var0 = LongLen / ShortLen
        var1 = LongLen / MiddlLen
        Value7 = (Value4 / Value1) * (var0)
        Value8 = (Value5 / Value2) * (var1)
        Value9 = (Value6 / Value3)
        UO := (Value7 + Value8 + Value9) / (var0 + var1 + 1)
    UO
// Ichimoku Cloud
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
ichimoku_cloud() =>
    conversionLine = donchian(9)
    baseLine = donchian(26)
    leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
    leadLine2 = donchian(52)
    [conversionLine, baseLine, leadLine1, leadLine2]

calcRatingMA(ma, src) => na(ma) or na(src) ? na : (ma == src ? 0 : ( ma < src ? 1 : -1 ))
calcRating(buy, sell) => buy ? 1 : ( sell ? -1 : 0 )
calcRatingAll() =>
    //============== MA =================
    SMA10 = ta.sma(close, 10)
    SMA20 = ta.sma(close, 20)
    SMA30 = ta.sma(close, 30)
    SMA50 = ta.sma(close, 50)
    SMA100 = ta.sma(close, 100)
    SMA200 = ta.sma(close, 200)

    EMA10 = ta.ema(close, 10)
    EMA20 = ta.ema(close, 20)
    EMA30 = ta.ema(close, 30)
    EMA50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
    EMA100 = ta.ema(close, 100)
    EMA200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

    HullMA9 = ta.hma(close, 9)

    // Volume Weighted Moving Average (VWMA)
    VWMA = ta.vwma(close, 20)

    [IC_CLine, IC_BLine, IC_Lead1, IC_Lead2] = ichimoku_cloud()

    // ======= Other =============
    // Relative Strength Index, RSI
    RSI = ta.rsi(close,14)

    // Stochastic
    lengthStoch = 14
    smoothKStoch = 3
    smoothDStoch = 3
    kStoch = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, lengthStoch), smoothKStoch)
    dStoch = ta.sma(kStoch, smoothDStoch)

    // Commodity Channel Index, CCI
    CCI = ta.cci(close, 20)

    // Average Directional Index
    float adxValue = na, float adxPlus = na, float adxMinus = na
    [P, M, V] = ta.dmi(14, 14)
    adxValue := V
    adxPlus := P
    adxMinus := M
    // Awesome Oscillator
    ao = AO()

    // Momentum
    Mom = ta.mom(close, 10)
    // Moving Average Convergence/Divergence, MACD
    [macdMACD, signalMACD, _] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
    // Stochastic RSI
    [Stoch_RSI_K, Stoch_RSI_D] = StochRSI()
    // Williams Percent Range
    WR = ta.wpr(14)

    // Bull / Bear Power
    BullPower = high - ta.ema(close, 13)
    BearPower = low - ta.ema(close, 13)
    // Ultimate Oscillator
    UO = uo(7,14,28)
    if not na(UO)
        UO := UO * 100
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    PriceAvg = ta.ema(close, 50)
    DownTrend = close < PriceAvg
    UpTrend = close > PriceAvg
    // calculate trading recommendation based on SMA/EMA
    float ratingMA = 0
    float ratingMAC = 0

    float ratingSMA10 = na
    if not na(SMA10)
        ratingSMA10 := calcRatingMA(SMA10, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA10
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingSMA20 = na
    if not na(SMA20)
        ratingSMA20 := calcRatingMA(SMA20, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA20
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingSMA30 = na
    if not na(SMA30)
        ratingSMA30 := calcRatingMA(SMA30, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA30
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingSMA50 = na
    if not na(SMA50)
        ratingSMA50 := calcRatingMA(SMA50, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA50
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingSMA100 = na
    if not na(SMA100)
        ratingSMA100 := calcRatingMA(SMA100, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA100
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingSMA200 = na
    if not na(SMA200)
        ratingSMA200 := calcRatingMA(SMA200, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingSMA200
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1

    float ratingEMA10 = na
    if not na(EMA10)
        ratingEMA10 := calcRatingMA(EMA10, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA10
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingEMA20 = na
    if not na(EMA20)
        ratingEMA20 := calcRatingMA(EMA20, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA20
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingEMA30 = na
    if not na(EMA30)
        ratingEMA30 := calcRatingMA(EMA30, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA30
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingEMA50 = na
    if not na(EMA50)
        ratingEMA50 := calcRatingMA(EMA50, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA50
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingEMA100 = na
    if not na(EMA100)
        ratingEMA100 := calcRatingMA(EMA100, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA100
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1
    float ratingEMA200 = na
    if not na(EMA200)
        ratingEMA200 := calcRatingMA(EMA200, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingEMA200
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1

    float ratingHMA = na
    if not na(HullMA9)
        ratingHMA := calcRatingMA(HullMA9, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingHMA
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1

    float ratingVWMA = na
    if not na(VWMA)
        ratingVWMA := calcRatingMA(VWMA, close)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingVWMA
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1

    float ratingIC = na
    if not (na(IC_Lead1) or na(IC_Lead2) or na(close) or na(close[1]) or na(IC_BLine) or na(IC_CLine))
        ratingIC := calcRating(
         IC_Lead1 > IC_Lead2 and close > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_BLine and close[1] < IC_CLine and close > IC_CLine,
         IC_Lead2 > IC_Lead1 and close < IC_Lead2 and close > IC_BLine and close[1] > IC_CLine and close < IC_CLine)
    if not na(ratingIC)
        ratingMA := ratingMA + ratingIC
        ratingMAC := ratingMAC + 1

    ratingMA := ratingMAC > 0 ? ratingMA / ratingMAC : na

    float ratingOther = 0
    float ratingOtherC = 0

    float ratingRSI = na
    if not(na(RSI) or na(RSI[1]))
        ratingRSI := calcRating(RSI < 30 and RSI[1] < RSI, RSI > 70 and RSI[1] > RSI)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingRSI

    float ratingStoch = na
    if not(na(kStoch) or na(dStoch) or na(kStoch[1]) or na(dStoch[1]))
        ratingStoch := calcRating(kStoch < 20 and dStoch < 20 and kStoch > dStoch and kStoch[1] < dStoch[1], kStoch > 80 and dStoch > 80 and kStoch < dStoch and kStoch[1] > dStoch[1])
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingStoch

    float ratingCCI = na
    if not(na(CCI) or na(CCI[1]))
        ratingCCI := calcRating(CCI < -100 and CCI > CCI[1], CCI > 100 and CCI < CCI[1])
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingCCI

    float ratingADX = na
    if not(na(adxValue) or na(adxPlus[1]) or na(adxMinus[1]) or na(adxPlus) or na(adxMinus))
        ratingADX := calcRating(adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] < adxMinus[1] and adxPlus > adxMinus, adxValue > 20 and adxPlus[1] > adxMinus[1] and adxPlus < adxMinus)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingADX

    float ratingAO = na
    if not(na(ao) or na(ao[1]))
        ratingAO := calcRating(ta.crossover(ao,0) or (ao > 0 and ao[1] > 0 and ao > ao[1] and ao[2] > ao[1]), ta.crossunder(ao,0) or (ao < 0 and ao[1] < 0 and ao < ao[1] and ao[2] < ao[1]))
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingAO

    float ratingMOM = na
    if not(na(Mom) or na(Mom[1]))
        ratingMOM := calcRating(Mom > Mom[1], Mom < Mom[1])
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingMOM

    float ratingMACD = na
    if not(na(macdMACD) or na(signalMACD))
        ratingMACD := calcRating(macdMACD > signalMACD, macdMACD < signalMACD)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingMACD

    float ratingStoch_RSI = na
    if not(na(DownTrend) or na(UpTrend) or na(Stoch_RSI_K) or na(Stoch_RSI_D) or na(Stoch_RSI_K[1]) or na(Stoch_RSI_D[1]))
        ratingStoch_RSI := calcRating(
         DownTrend and Stoch_RSI_K < 20 and Stoch_RSI_D < 20 and Stoch_RSI_K > Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] < Stoch_RSI_D[1],
         UpTrend and Stoch_RSI_K > 80 and Stoch_RSI_D > 80 and Stoch_RSI_K < Stoch_RSI_D and Stoch_RSI_K[1] > Stoch_RSI_D[1])
    if not na(ratingStoch_RSI)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingStoch_RSI

    float ratingWR = na
    if not(na(WR) or na(WR[1]))
        ratingWR := calcRating(WR < -80 and WR > WR[1], WR > -20 and WR < WR[1])
    if not na(ratingWR)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingWR

    float ratingBBPower = na
    if not(na(UpTrend) or na(DownTrend) or na(BearPower) or na(BearPower[1]) or na(BullPower) or na(BullPower[1]))
        ratingBBPower := calcRating(
         UpTrend and BearPower < 0 and BearPower > BearPower[1],
         DownTrend and BullPower > 0 and BullPower < BullPower[1])
    if not na(ratingBBPower)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingBBPower

    float ratingUO = na
    if not(na(UO))
        ratingUO := calcRating(UO > 70, UO < 30)
    if not na(ratingUO)
        ratingOtherC := ratingOtherC + 1
        ratingOther := ratingOther + ratingUO

    ratingOther := ratingOtherC > 0 ? ratingOther / ratingOtherC : na

    float ratingTotal = 0
    float ratingTotalC = 0
    if not na(ratingMA)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingMA
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    if not na(ratingOther)
        ratingTotal := ratingTotal + ratingOther
        ratingTotalC := ratingTotalC + 1
    ratingTotal := ratingTotalC > 0 ? ratingTotal / ratingTotalC : na

    [ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA]

StrongBound = 0.5
WeakBound = 0.1

getSignal(ratingTotal, ratingOther, ratingMA) =>
    float _res = ratingTotal
    if ratingSignal == "MAs"
        _res := ratingMA
    if ratingSignal == "Oscillators"
        _res := ratingOther
    _res

[ratingTotalCurrent, ratingOtherCurrent, ratingMACurrent]  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, calcRatingAll())
[ratingTotal_mtf1,   ratingOther_mtf1,   ratingMA_mtf1]    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, mtf1, calcRatingAll())
[ratingTotal_mtf2,   ratingOther_mtf2,   ratingMA_mtf2]    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, mtf2, calcRatingAll())
[ratingTotal_mtf3,   ratingOther_mtf3,   ratingMA_mtf3]    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, mtf3, calcRatingAll())
[ratingTotal_mtf4,   ratingOther_mtf4,   ratingMA_mtf4]    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, mtf4, calcRatingAll())
[ratingTotal_mtf5,   ratingOther_mtf5,   ratingMA_mtf5]    = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, mtf5, calcRatingAll())

tradeSignal = getSignal(ratingTotalCurrent, ratingOtherCurrent, ratingMACurrent)

calcRatingStatus(value) =>
    if na(value)
        "-"
    else if -StrongBound > value
        "Strong\nSell"
    else if value < -WeakBound
        "Sell   "
    else if value > StrongBound
        "Strong\nBuy "
    else if value > WeakBound
        "Buy    "
    else
        "Neutral"

allRatingsArray = array.from("All", calcRatingStatus(ratingTotalCurrent), calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal_mtf1), calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal_mtf2),
                  calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal_mtf3), calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal_mtf4), calcRatingStatus(ratingTotal_mtf5))

oscRatingsArray = array.from("Osc", calcRatingStatus(ratingOtherCurrent), calcRatingStatus(ratingOther_mtf1), calcRatingStatus(ratingOther_mtf2),
                  calcRatingStatus(ratingOther_mtf3), calcRatingStatus(ratingOther_mtf4), calcRatingStatus(ratingOther_mtf5))

maRatingsArray = array.from("MAs", calcRatingStatus(ratingMACurrent), calcRatingStatus(ratingMA_mtf1), calcRatingStatus(ratingMA_mtf2),
                 calcRatingStatus(ratingMA_mtf3), calcRatingStatus(ratingMA_mtf4), calcRatingStatus(ratingMA_mtf5))

currentRes = res==""?timeframe.period=="D"?"1D":
                     timeframe.period=="W"?"1W":
                     timeframe.period=="M"?"1M":
                     timeframe.period:res
allResArray = array.from("TF", currentRes, mtf1, mtf2, mtf3, mtf4, mtf5)
usedMtfArray = array.from(true, true, useMtf1, useMtf2, useMtf3, useMtf4, useMtf5)

removeUnused(duplicatedIndex) =>
    if array.size(duplicatedIndex) > 0
        for j=0 to array.size(duplicatedIndex)-1
            int currentDupIndex  = array.shift(duplicatedIndex)
            array.remove(allResArray,     currentDupIndex-j)
            array.remove(usedMtfArray,    currentDupIndex-j)
            array.remove(allRatingsArray, currentDupIndex-j)
            array.remove(oscRatingsArray, currentDupIndex-j)
            array.remove(maRatingsArray,  currentDupIndex-j)

eraseDuplicatedAndDisabledTf() =>
    int[] duplicatedIndex = array.new_int()
    for m=1 to array.size(allResArray)-1
        bool isCurrentMtfDisabled = array.get(usedMtfArray, m) == false
        if isCurrentMtfDisabled
            array.push(duplicatedIndex, m)
    removeUnused(duplicatedIndex)

    for m=1 to array.size(allResArray)-1
        int firstSearchElemIndex = array.indexof(allResArray, array.get(allResArray, m))
        int lastSearchElemIndex = array.lastindexof(allResArray, array.get(allResArray, m))
        if firstSearchElemIndex == lastSearchElemIndex or array.indexof(duplicatedIndex, lastSearchElemIndex) != -1
            continue
        string searchElem = array.get(allResArray, firstSearchElemIndex)
        for i=firstSearchElemIndex+1 to lastSearchElemIndex
            string currentElem = array.get(allResArray, i)
            if searchElem == currentElem
                array.push(duplicatedIndex, i)
    removeUnused(duplicatedIndex)

poscond = tradeSignal > WeakBound
negcond = tradeSignal < -WeakBound
posseries = poscond ? tradeSignal : 0
negseries = negcond ? tradeSignal : 0
count_rising(plot) =>
    v_plot = plot > 0 ? plot : -plot
    var count = 0
    if v_plot == 0
        count := 0
    else if v_plot >= v_plot[1]
        count := math.min(5, count + 1)
    else if v_plot < v_plot[1]
        count := math.max(1, count - 1)
    count
poscount = count_rising(posseries)
negcount = count_rising(negseries)
_pc = poscond ? poscount : negcond ? negcount : 0

colorTransp(col, transp) =>
    red = color.r(col)
    green = color.g(col)
    blue = color.b(col)
    color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp)

hline(1, color=colorTransp(colBuy, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(0.5, color=colorTransp(colBuy, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(-1, color=colorTransp(colSell, 50), linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(-0.5, color=colorTransp(colSell, 50), linestyle=hline.style_dashed)

f_cellBgColor(_signal) =>
    _returnColor = tableTitleColor
    if _signal == "Sell   "
        _returnColor := colSell
    else if _signal == "Strong\nSell"
        _returnColor := colStrongSell
    else if _signal == "Buy    "
        _returnColor := colBuy
    else if _signal == "Strong\nBuy "
        _returnColor := colStrongBuy
    else if _signal == "Neutral" or _signal == "-"
        _returnColor := colNeutral
    _returnColor

f_cellAlign(_cellTitle) =>
    _align = text.align_left
    if _cellTitle == "MAs" or _cellTitle == "Osc" or _cellTitle == "All" or _cellTitle == "-"
        _align := text.align_center
    _align

f_addCell(_table, _column, _row, _cellTitle) =>
    table.cell(_table, _column, _row, _cellTitle, text_color=color.white, text_halign=f_cellAlign(_cellTitle), bgcolor=f_cellBgColor(_cellTitle), text_size=size.small)

f_drawInfo() =>
    var t1 = table.new(position.middle_right, 4, array.size(allRatingsArray), frame_width=2, frame_color=color.white, border_width=1, border_color=color.white)
    eraseDuplicatedAndDisabledTf()
    timeframesCount = array.size(allResArray)
    if timeframesCount < 3
        for i=0 to timeframesCount-1
            f_addCell(t1, i, 1, array.get(maRatingsArray, i))
            f_addCell(t1, i, 2, array.get(oscRatingsArray, i))
            f_addCell(t1, i, 3, array.get(allRatingsArray, i))
    else
        for i=0 to timeframesCount-1
            f_addCell(t1, 0, i, array.get(allResArray, i))
            if ratingSignal == "All"
                f_addCell(t1, 1, i, array.get(maRatingsArray, i))
                f_addCell(t1, 2, i, array.get(oscRatingsArray, i))
                f_addCell(t1, 3, i, array.get(allRatingsArray, i))
            if ratingSignal == "Oscillators"
                f_addCell(t1, 1, i, array.get(oscRatingsArray, i))
            if ratingSignal == "MAs"
                f_addCell(t1, 1, i, array.get(maRatingsArray, i))

col_buy = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, 0.0, 0.2, colNeutral, colStrongBuy)
col_sell = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.0, colStrongSell, colNeutral)
col_gradient = color.from_gradient(tradeSignal, -0.2, 0.2, col_sell, col_buy)

if barstate.islast
    f_drawInfo()

plot(tradeSignal, title="Rating", linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_columns, color = color.new(col_gradient, 50 - _pc * 10))
_cond1 = ta.crossunder(tradeSignal, -WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond1, "Sell", "Ratings changed to Sell")
_cond2 = ta.crossover(tradeSignal, WeakBound)
alertcondition(_cond2, "Buy", "Ratings changed to Buy")
_cond3 = ta.crossunder(tradeSignal, -StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond3, "Strong Sell", "Ratings changed to Strong Sell")
_cond4 = ta.crossover(tradeSignal, StrongBound)
alertcondition(_cond4, "Strong Buy", "Ratings changed to Strong Buy")
```

And CCI

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Commodity Channel Index", shorttitle="CCI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(hlc3, title="Source")
ma = ta.sma(src, length)
cci = (src - ma) / (0.015 * ta.dev(src, length))
plot(cci, "CCI", color=#2962FF)
band1 = hline(100, "Upper Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(0, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(-100, "Lower Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

typeMA = input.string(title = "Method", defval = "SMA", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="Smoothing")
smoothingLength = input.int(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")

smoothingLine = ma(cci, smoothingLength, typeMA)
plot(smoothingLine, title="Smoothing Line", color=#f37f20, display=display.none)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pinescript you should have only one line with :

```
//@version5
```

and

```
indicator(title="....)
```

So you can copy paste the two indicators in a new indicator window (but copy only once the two lines above).
Then you should change all the variable name of the second indicator (CCI).
For example change

```
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
```

to

```
CCIlength = input.int(20, minval=1)
```

Then you want to know when the Technical rating is buy or strong buy in one hour, but the Technical Rating indicator use already several timeframe so I think you should not worry and use :

```
if _cond2 or _cond4 then
    // We have a 'buy' or 'strong buy'
```

Then you want to know when the CCI indicator is above -70 on 1 day : Choose 1 day on your chart and use :

```
if CCIsmoothingLine > -70 then
    // We have a CCI > -70
```

Comment: thanks for responding, things are much clearer now if you can also tell me how to fetch cci data from 1 day time frame while being on 1 hr timeframe, I know it's not any different from the solution you suggested but I'm much more comfortable with 1 hr chart

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it helped you. To fetch on different timeframe I suggest you to ask a new question.

Comment: I've accepted your answer and what I meant by fetching is I want to get an alert when CCI on 1 day time frame is above -70 and technical rating is buy or strong buy on 1 hr timeframe while being on 1 hr chart and it wont be possible I think without fetching the data from 1 d time frame, I should've mentioned that in the question, do you think you can help me with this here or do I still need to ask another question?

Comment: @shahzaib We can definitively help you. On stackoverflow you must ask one question at a time, and you will get precise answer. Please open a new question about your problem with the timeframe, you will get answers